# ',' expected ts(1005) [19,10]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I got this error in react. Is this is a syntax error or any other? Already check whole code in several times and couldn't solve it. This the code that i used. Shall i use ts here? And the error message screenshot added in following

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from './node_modules/react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';

function HomeScreen(props) {      
    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
    const { products, loading, error} = productList;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () =>{
            dispatch(listProducts());

        return () =>{
            //
        };
    }, []) 

    return loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : 
        error ? <div>{error}</div> :
    
    <ul className="products">
    {
        products.map(product =>
    <li key={product._id}>
            <div className="product">
            < Link to= {'/product/' + product._id}>  
                <img className="products-image" src={product.image} alt="product"/>
                </ Link>
                <div className="product-name">
                    < Link to= {'/product/' + product._id}> {product.name} </Link>
                    </div>
                <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
                <div className="product-price">Rs.{product.price}</div>  
                <div className="product-rating">{product.rating} Stars ({product.numReivews}Reviews)</div>
            </div>
        </li>) 
    }
            
    </ul>

}

export default HomeScreen;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a syntax error. You're missing a `}` on the async function you've assigned to `fetchData` in the `useEffect` callback.

Comment: When posting a question related to an error with a line number, help people out by indicating what line in the code you've quoted is the line mentioned. There aren't any line numbers in code blocks as shown on SO, and people tend to leave out parts of files when they post them anyway, so rather than making us count and hope that you haven't left some out, show us where the line is.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and give ESLint a try because that code isn't formatted properly... And with a set of rules your productivity will increase (and your team's productivity as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one `}`. Correct way is this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () =>{
        dispatch(listProducts());
    } //<- this one
    return () =>{
        //
    };
}}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

it's a syntax error you forgot the } in useEffect try this

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () =>{
        dispatch(listProducts());

    return () =>{
        //
    };
}}, [])
```